# Angular Consume Data from Rest API

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, maven, jersey

I'm trying to retrieve data from a java service using Angular and jersey servlet, but I keep getting `404 Not Found` error for `http://localhost:8080/ContactList/users`.

Here is my app.js

```
angular.module('ContactList', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ngMessages'])
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $routeProvider
        .when('/ContactList', {
            controller: 'MyCtrl1',
            templateUrl: '/ContactList/resources/html/view.html'
        });
});
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ContactList/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

controller.js

```
angular.module('ContactList')
.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'UserFactory', function ($scope, UserFactory) {
UserFactory.get({}, function (userFactory) {
    $scope.firstname = userFactory.firstName;
})
}]);
```

Services.js

```
angular.module('ContactList')
.factory('UserFactory', function ($resource) {
return $resource('/ContactList/users', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {},
        isArray: false
    }
})
});
```

And finally my UserRestService.java

```
    import javax.ws.rs.GET;
    import javax.ws.rs.Path;
    import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

    public class UserRestService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getDefaultUserInJSON() {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        return userService.getDefaultUser();
    }
}
```

In my view, I'm simply trying to output the result from the Rest call:

`Result from RESTful service is: {{ firstname }}`

Any ideas on why it's not hitting the service? My initial suspicion was my `$resource` in my `services.js`.

Edit - Tomcat 7:run error

---

```
`Running war on http://localhost:8080/
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at C:\ContactList\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath:
Feb 21, 2017 6:23:55 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 21, 2017 6:23:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Feb 21, 2017 6:23:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Feb 21, 2017 6:23:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializer(ContextConfig.java:1670)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1562)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
`
```

POM.xml

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>ContactList</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <!--Spring-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Oracle driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
           <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
           <version>LATEST</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
           <version>1.9</version>
       </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
            <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
       <finalName>ContactList</finalName>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>${java-version}</source>
                   <target>${java-version}</target>
               </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>2.6</version>
             <configuration>
                <warName>ContactList</warName>
                <webappDirectory>../ContactList/target/ContactList</webappDirectory>
             </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
              <executions>
                  <execution>
                      <id>install</id>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <goals>
                          <goal>sources</goal>
                      </goals>
                  </execution>
              </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2</version>
              <configuration>
                  <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>

</project>`
```

Comment: Please try hitting the service from the browser to discard the possibility of a server missconfig: `http://localhost:8080/ContactList/users`

Comment: `HTTP Status 404 - /ContactList/users

type Status report

message /ContactList/users

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.70`

Comment: You need to fix that on your server side first

Comment: Not entirely sure where to start with that. Is that maybe a Tomcat config issue?

Comment: Try removing `ContactList` - this does not appear to be part of your URL path.

Comment: @MikeHoldsworth `No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/users`

Comment: Please confirm that <param-value>com.wwt.ContactList</param-value> is the value of your UserRestService  package

Comment: @artemisian That is the directory path leading up to UserRestService. UserRestService resides in that folder.

Comment: So in UserRestService.java the first line reads
`package com.wwt.ContactList;` ?

Comment: Yes, correct `package com.wwt.ContactList;`

Comment: Path to web resources goes `{protocol}://{serverip}:{port}/{contextRoot}/{resource}`  Your resource appears to be `/users`. Have you checked the context root? As artemisian said, you need to be able to hit the EP from a browser before trying from your application. You could try adding `@Path("/")` to your `getDefaultUserInJSON` function - also, try adding a / to the end of your URL

Comment: @Mike Holdsworth I was going to say that try adding `@Path("/")` to method `getDefaultUserInJSON`

Comment: Modified UserRestService above. Still same 404.

Comment: In Tomcat, I have my application context set as `ContactList`

Comment: Hmm, then try `http://localhost:8080/ContactList/ContactList/users`

Comment: Please check my answer and see if it solves it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on our original question comments.

First, please remove the `@Path("/")` from `getDefaultUserInJSON` as it's no needed.

Second, this is a problem with the deployment to Tomcat. Check that in the war that's being deployed, within it, file WEB-INF/web.xml has the same content as in your project. But let's try this, let's run Tomcat embedded and let's make it work. *You will need to install Maven if you don't have it installed already*.

The following is a minimal pom file. Just copy it:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.wwt</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestTest</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RestTest Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>RestTest</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Now, just open a terminal on your project root folder and execute `mvn clean install tomcat7:run`. You should be able to hit without any issues url `http://localhost:8080/ContactList/users`

In your pom try updating the below dependency (add `<scope>provide</scope>`) and see if that solves it.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1</version>
   <scope>provide</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Yes, I have my pom all set up and maven is installed.

Comment: See above edited error I get when running `mvn clean install tomcat7:run`

Comment: Please post your pom

Comment: Pom posted above. I've tinkered with it quite a bit. Probably broke something.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer cannot be cast to javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`...is what I now get

Comment: Im not sure what you are trying to accomplish. You have a lot of spring dependencies. Why dont you use spring mvc to expose your rest services? Is very easy: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136360/discussion-between-andrew-and-artemisian).